# Where should I add my subview to have it UNDER my table view in a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm using parse's `PFQueryTableViewController`, which is almost exactly the same as a `UITableViewController` except it handles some querying in the background.

My goal is to place a static toolbar at the bottom of the screen. I decided to do this by giving `tableView` a smaller frame, and creating and adding my toolbar subview below the `tableView`, as a subview to the same view that the `tableView` is a subview of.

Here's a photo. I am trying to add my toolbar to the little white space at the bottom of the screen. That whitespace does NOT scroll with the table view:

[image]

I have tried `[self.view addSubview: toolbar]`, however, this just adds it to the tableView, and as a result, my toolbar scrolls with it. I can't seem to find any documentation on the view hierarchy for a UITableViewController. Anyone know where I should add my toolbar subview? I should also mention that all of this is sitting inside of a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Footerview will be the best place for this

Answer (score 0):

A `PFQueryTableViewController` (like all `UITableViewController`s) has a table view as its `view`.

If you want to have other views within the view controller, either don't use a table view controller, or subclass `UINavigationController`.

Alternatively, you can set the view controller's [`toolbarItems`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/toolbarItems) property, and the navigation controller will take care of making and configuring a standard toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

implement viewFAorHeaderInSection delegate method of UITableView:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

    UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 90)];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return customView;
 }
```

and heightForFooterInSection

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 80;
}
```

it should solove your problem.